# Read key from cose_key returned in signData()

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib, public-key, message-signing

The following `(await window.cardano['<wallet>'].enable()).signData('<addr>', '<payload>')`

Returns an object
`{ key: <key>, signature: <sig> }`

I'm successfully parsing the key to a CoseKey with `ermugo/message-signing` in node.js, but struggling to pull the header which contains the key. Reading [CIP-0030](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/tree/master/CIP-0030#apisigndataaddr-address-payload-bytes-promisedatasignature) I believe it is contained within the headers as `x`. Could someone explain how I read this in code, please? Thanks for your time.

edit: if there is documentation that explains how to do this please show me the way.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's mentioned in CIP-0030 that the key for the header associated with the public key is `-2`, I spent some time in the debugger and managed to fetch it with this code.

```
const coseKey = MessageSigning.COSEKey.from_bytes(Buffer.from(key, 'hex'));

const keyHeaderBytes = coseKey.header(MessageSigning.Label.new_int(MessageSigning.Int.new_i32(-2))).as_bytes();
```

Not sure if this is the optimal solution but it seems to work. Open to feedback.